# Найти в данной категории все значения field и вывести в блоке якорями

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Делаю сайт WP + Woocommerce. Задача такая: вывести в категории отдельно параметр всех товаров - Диаметр.
Пытаюсь вывести вот так:

```
<?php
        global $woocommerce ,$product, $post;

        $num_field      = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'diametr_number_field', true );
        if ( $num_field ) { ?>
<a href="#<?php echo $num_field ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php echo $num_field ?>
    </a>
<?php
        
} 
         ?>
```

Но почему-то выводится Диаметр только первого товара. Как я понимаю нужно перебрать весь массив, но я новичок и не получается. Помогите, пожалуйста.